# Etiquette when mentioning an idea in an answer that was previously mentioned in a comment

Tags: discussion, comments, review

What to with an answer that is a direct copy of a previous comment?

[like this case](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32385/how-to-name-buffers-shell)

Comment: Did you copy the wrong link? That answer is not a copy of a comment.

Comment: there's nothing new in the answer, it's just what @wvxvw suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in question:

> Go to the buffer you want to rename, in your case `*shell*`. Then type `M-x rename-buffer` and enter the new name for this buffer.

There are two comments that mention `rename-buffer`:

> I would normally call `C-u M-x shell` - in this way Emacs offers to name the buffer it creates. But if I forget, there's always the `M-x rename-buffer`. Or are you asking for an advise on what that name should be?
>
> FWIW, I bind `rename-buffer` to a key (and I use it fairly often).

Given that the question is about naming buffers, it's unsurprising that multiple people would mention `rename-buffer`. The mention of this function is the only similarity between the answer and the comments. This answer is not a “direct copy of a previous comment”. The answer is original writing.

Copying someone's *writing* is covered both by law and by site rules. The law states that creative writing is covered by [copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright). This site's [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) state that all posted content (including answers and comments, as well as questions, tag wikis, etc.) are licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). This license gives anyone the right to copy posted content anywhere, provided that they give proper attribution.

In addition, the [site rules](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) require attribution for any content that is posted to the site and copied from someone else. This is independent of any requirement due to copyright.

Copying *ideas* is another matter. Neither the law nor the site rules require attribution for ideas. Nonetheless, it is appreciated to acknowledge the source if you copy someone's idea. However, if you come up with the same idea independently, you do not need to research if someone had the same idea first.

Mentioning `rename-buffer when replying to a question about buffer names is obvious. No credit is due here.

Comment: thanks @Gilles , I was thinking that a very short answer that is posted three months after the discussion in the comments and brings nothing new should be flagged, as I can't see a reason for posting that answer in the first place, but I accept your answer objectively.